# How do I make a public view model base with WinRT classes?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I wanted to create an abstract base class for all of my view models, but I'm running into accessibility issues and can't seem to navigate through the errors. Here's an example of my code:

```
public ref class ViewModelBase {
    ...
}

public ref class OtherViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    ...
}
```

When I define my code as state above, I get the following error:

**error C4585: 'MyNamespace::ViewModelBase' : A WinRT 'public ref class' must either be sealed or derive from an existing unsealed class**

If, instead, I make ViewModelBase private, I get this error:

**error C3213: base class 'MyNamespace::ViewModelBase' is less accessible than 'OtherViewModel'**

This seems like it should be incredibly simple. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are attempting is not strictly possible in C++/CX, as in VS 2012 C++/CX does not support public class inheritance for general-purpose scenarios.  It is only supported enough to have the XAML scenarios work; the only possible public unsealed types are those  found under the `Windows::UI::Xaml` namespace, and users are not able to author their own public unsealed types.

If you want to have a base class for all your view models, your only options to make all your classes private or to inherit from a base class from `Windows::UI::Xaml` (such as `DependencyObject`).

Each of these approaches has drawbacks:

- using DependencyObject as your base makes all your viewmodels STA objects (so they can only be manipulated from the UI thread) in addition to having a lot of overhead that isn't really necessary.
- Making your classes private means you cannot use the `[Bindable]` attribute to do databinding, so you would need to have a private databinding implementation.  (Your private class would need to implement `ICustomPropertyProvider` and related interfaces.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I noticed that a BindableBase class came with one of the new project templates and that it used DependencyObject. Although I find this limitation fairly frustrating, it's nice to understand well enough to proceed.

Comment: Yeah, this restriction showed up somewhat late in the product cycle, and at the request of the Windows Runtime team who wished to preserve that functionality (general runtime class inheritance) for a future release, when we would have more runway to design a more coherent story.

All language projections have this limitation, but it is less painful in C#, as runtime reflection allows them to support databinding for private classes.

Comment: That is the worst design I have ever seen, completely destroy the OO paradigm.

Answer (score -1):

The "sealed" keyword means that the class cannot be inherited from.  Your implementation should look something like this:

```
ref class ViewModelBase sealed
```

If you want to inherit from ViewModelBase then you need to have only the subclasses be `ref` classes like this:

```
class ViewModelBase

...

public ref class OtherViewModel sealed : ViewModelBase
```

Comment: Right, I definitely don't want the Base to be sealed -- it's whole purpose is to be inherited. And the second example produces errors. ref classes can only derive from other ref classes or interfaces.

Comment: I've possibly missed something.  I took my example from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699870.aspx